# Sorry, user localguest is not allowed X as root in local-in-sc

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, oracle

I know this is a common question and has been asked a lot, but I cant seem to find a solution that works for me, I work on vm virtual box and I want to install sudo and gtkmm3 library and it just wouldnt let me.

````
uid=1001(localguest) gid=1001(localguest) groups=1001(localguest)```
 ```sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for localguest on local-in-sc:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User localguest may run the following commands on local-in-sc:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount, /sbin/mount.cifs, /bin/umount```
````

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details, nor clear text saying what file or command you're showing the results for (it's best if we're not making assumptions, but are clearly told!)

Comment: I work in a Linux OS, Ubuntu, on Oracle VirtualBox, I'm trying to install a library (gtkmm-3.0) but it keeps giving me that user localguest is not allowed "usr/bin/apt-get install (gtkmm ...) as root on local-in-sc. So I tried to see what the localguest is allowed to do and this is what I got, sorry for not clarifying in the first place

Comment: Providing a release & system details lets me issue commands & see likely pitfalls, but given I still have no OS & release details I cannot look for you (besides some Ubuntu systems don't use *deb* packages but use *snap* only with everything running inside containers which creates extra pitfalls for some functions... and you've not excluded any such system yet)